# Can we change the log message format in sysklogd (similar to creating templates in rsyslog)

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I have to send data from rsyslog in a format like this 
Eg:

```
fac:kern HELLO pri:info HELLO May  5 14:06:31 nitish-VirtualBox kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
```

So i created a new conf file called `"my.conf"` in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` and added the following lines in it

```
$template myFormat,"fac:%syslogfacility-text% HELLO pri:%syslogpriority-text% HELLO %timegenerated% %msg%\n" 
*.* /home/user/log.txt;myFormat
```

so that i can strip this log message in my java application to get facility name,priority name and rest of the message.Here string "HELLO" acts as a filter element.

i can create templates in **rsyslog** and send incoming **syslog** messages in this format to log.txt.
But now i have to send log messages from **sysklogd**(not syslog-ng and not rsyslog) in the same format but **sysklogd** does not support templates.So is there a way to change the log message format in **sysklogd**

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no. Your best bet is to get it out of sysklogd and over to a daemon which is capable of manipulating the template (even if it's by relaying to a second syslogd on the same system).

Comment: But i would not know the priority or the facility info which i need from the log message.Because i tried forwarding msgs from syslog.conf like *.* /home/nitish/nitish.log and i got message in this format   Example: May 11 15:14:20 nitish-VirtualBox syslogd 1.5.0#6ubuntu1: restart.
May 11 15:14:20 nitish-VirtualBox sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root